# Animate adding/removing items from ListView with CursorAdapter possible?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I was just wondering if it is possible to animate the removing/adding from items when I requery my cursor (and for example some underlying data changed). Or do I have to check the differences manually and assign/remove them from my listview to get the desired animations?

I use a slightely different version of [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) and created my own cursor-adapter for usage.

So basically I'd like to know a good way of how to check if there are differences inside of the cursor (element missing, element added) so I could animate their apperance.

Comment: use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html